# XDocument problematic characters

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm using XDocument to describe a tree of folders' names.
Some folders have special characters, like " ' " and I get an XmlException saying such characters cannot be included in a name.
I've added the following declaration to the document's constructing:
`public XDocument file= new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));`
but I still get the exception. I'd appreciate any solution that will enable comfortable work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use those characters in element names or attribute names. You can only specify them in attribute values, XText objects or CDATA sections (so long as they are encoded of course).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `'` with `&apos;`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references for a complete list.

Please note that these will not all work by default with XML (see also the Wikipedia page). Most of these have to be defined. Only the following work by default:

```
&apos; => '
&quot; => "
&amp; => &
&gt; => >
&lt; => <
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! Can you post a link to a complete collection of such characters?

Comment: I've added those replaces, but now the same exception is thrown because of the & character... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please paste an example of the XML that is causing you problems to the question.

Comment: For example, after changing "Sam's bug" to "Sam&apos;s_bug", and creating a node: `XElement xNode = new XElement("Sam&apos;s_bug");`

Comment: Within node names, these constructions are illegal. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#d0e804 for more information.

Comment: Ok, but they do exist as folders' names. Any suggestion how to handle this?

Comment: Change it into an attribute: `<folder name="Sa&apos;s_bug"`

Comment: but the name is needed for creation, and also to locate a node by it - when you're adding subfolders for example. Any ideas?